# How can I Extract Road Networks from Openstreet map with python?

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I want to extract road network geometry from [Openstreetmap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=13/48.8581/2.3494) with Python.

How can this be done?
I haven't done anything of this sort before, any help would be appreciated!

**Desired output:**

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: you might want to check out the [osmnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx) package

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Warped1 use [osmnx](https://pypi.org/project/osmnx/)

Here is a way to get the street network information:

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Paris, France')
ox.plot_graph(G)
```

**Output:**
[image]

[Here](https://geoffboeing.com/2016/11/osmnx-python-street-networks/) is more information about the package and also an example similar to the one you have.

Cheers!